# How to do RF reset or re-activation of a Mifare ultralight c?

Tags: android, flutter, nfc, mifare, 3des

I am trying to program a 3DES key to my Mifare ultralight c, using Flutter. And this method is called through a method channel to android.

from the [documentation](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF0ICU2.pdf) section 7.5.7, it says that `A re-programmed authentication key is only valid for authentication after a RF reset or a re-activation`. I don't know how to do reset or re-activation, can anyone help?

here's my code with `tag` being `IUltralightC`

*NFC tag used: NXP Mifare ultralight C (Ntag213)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to physically remove the Tag from the RF field, but I guess that you want to do it programmatically.

Another way that might work is to stop and start your foreground tag detection (you don't show how you are detecting the Tag detection) and this seem only work if you are using `enableReaderMode` Android API, I don't do this myself in my Native Android App but if I simulate it by pausing the App then the Tag is detected again (I tried simulating using an App that does not use `enableReaderMode` Android API and it was not re-detected)